# Scala Partial Unification inference notation/synax explained

Tags: scala

I am doing some readying on Partial unification.

Although I believe I understand how the compiler handle it as per:

https://gist.github.com/djspiewak/7a81a395c461fd3a09a6941d4cd040f2

https://www.sderosiaux.com/articles/2018/04/12/an-ode-to-the-kind-projector-and-to-the-partial-unification-of-scala/

What I do not understand is the following notation/syntax

```
// required
F[_]

// provided
Foo[Int, String, Boolean]

// inferred
[A]Foo[Int, String, A]
```

or

```
// required
F[_, _, _]

// provided
Foo[Monad, Int, String, Boolean, Unit]

// inferred
[A, B, C]Foo[Monad, Int, A, B, C]
```

Again I understand what is happening, i just don't understand why they wrote it as such, and how to read it i.e.

```
[A, B, C]Foo[Monad, Int, A, B, C]
```

that is, the syntax/notation of the inferred part.

Can someone explain where the notation/syntax comes from and how to read it in english ?

## EDIT1

Many thanks to @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez thus far very helpful. Although I am left with one last puzzle

In the following I do not get the last line

```
def show[F[_], A](f: F[A]) = ???

                   List[Int]: F[_],A = List, Int      // perfect match
              Option[String]: F[_],A = Option, String // perfect match
       Either[Error, String]: F[_],A = [T]Either[Error, T], String
Triple[Int, String, Boolean]: F[_],A = [T]Triple[Int, String, T], Boolean
Free[IO[_], Option[String]]]: F[_],A = [T]Free[IO, T], Option[String]
               String => Int: F[_],A = [T]String => T, Int
                         Int: F[_],A = Any, Nothing
```

Namely

```
Int: F[_],A = Any, Nothing
```

I don't get that unification. Can some explain ?

Comment: Is like a lambda, is just the syntax of a function. Give me a type `A` and I will return `F[Int, String, A]` - And it works by going from right to left.

Comment: Where can I find example of that syntax so it does not feel like magic

Comment: WDYM? That is not even valid syntax is just the notation the compiler used to print them. I do not understand what feels about magic on that and not in `x => x + 1`?

Comment: Understood ! How can I get the compiler to print that out for me ?

Comment: No idea, I believe when there is a type error it will show what was expected and what was inferred; IIRC is in that moment that it uses that syntax. In any case, why does it matters? What is your end goal here?

Comment: Understood ! As always many thanks 